# How do I optimize my code so that I don't have to call the entire array every time in views from an API in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm making a sports app to learn Rails. I've figured out how to call the API and display it how I want, but right now, I'm putting the full array in my view every time I want to call any key.

For instance, I want to make a page that shows the starting line-ups for teams using the JSON from the API, and right now I have it displaying, but the code within the view itself is pretty big and ugly.

My view:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'lineups' %>

<div id="lineupcontainter">
    <div id= "team1lineup">
    
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][0]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][0]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
            
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][1]["player_name"] %> 
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][1]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>

        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][2]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][2]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
            
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][3]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][3]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
            
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][4]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][4]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>

        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][5]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][5]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
            
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][6]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][6]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
            
        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][7]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][7]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>

        <div id= "player1"><%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][8]["player_name"] %>
            <div id= "playerphotos"> <%= image_tag @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"][8]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %> </div> </div>
    </div>
```

My controller

```
def game1
    @response = RestClient.get "https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/between/2022-02-01/2022-02-04/62?api_token=____&include=lineup.player,"
    {content_type: :json, accept: :json, "user_key": "____"}
    
    @schedule = JSON.parse(@response) 
    render JSON: @schedule
end
```

What can I do to create something where I don't have to call the entire array every time I want to put something in views?

Comment: A solution might be to only query the API once (per day/hour) in a background job and then store the data in the database. When rendering the view you can then just load the data from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
<div id="lineupcontainter">
<div id= "team1lineup">
  <% @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"].each do |cur_schedule|%>
    <div id= "player1">
      <%= cur_schedule["player_name"] %>
      <div id= "playerphotos"> 
        <%= image_tag cur_schedule.dig("player", "data", "image_path") %>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Also, your controller has some redundant logic. You are parsing a JSON string and turning it into a ruby hash, then you take that hash and render it as a JSON string. You should be able to render the json directly.

Comment: You could also reduce `@schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"]` by doing it in the controller. With your loop, this is just moving the indexing from one place to another, but if it is repeated in the template, it is a huge simplfication.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the lines of code in your template, you can iterate over the instance variable in the .erb file. This bit of code *should* work if you put it in your erb file:

```rb
<div id="lineupcontainter">
  <div id="team1lineup">

    <!-- iterating on team 1 -->
    <%= @schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"].map.with_index do |data, index| %>

      <!-- index will increase by 1 each iteration, starts at 0 -->
      <div id="player1"><%= data[index]["player_name"] %>
        <div id="playerphotos"> <%= image_tag data[index]["player"]["data"]["image_path"] %></div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would recommend parsing that data in your controller before sending it to the template, something like this:

```rb
def game1
  @response = RestClient.get "https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/between/2022-02-01/2022-02-04/62?api_token=____&include=lineup.player,"
  {content_type: :json, accept: :json, "user_key": "____"}

  schedule = JSON.parse(@response)
  # in the ERB, replace schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"] with @lineup_data 
  @lineup_data = schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"]

  render JSON: @lineup_data
end
```

Another note: you do not need to call `render json: @schedule` in your controller. That will call `.to_json` on the instance variable and it's unnecessary when rendering data in an ERB template. The Rails MVC design allows the template to access instance variables defined in controllers. See [section 2.2.8 Rendering JSON](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) for documentation.

```rb
def game1
  @response = RestClient.get "https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/fixtures/between/2022-02-01/2022-02-04/62?api_token=____&include=lineup.player,"
  {content_type: :json, accept: :json, "user_key": "____"}

  schedule = JSON.parse(@response)
  @lineup_data = schedule["data"][0]["lineup"]["data"]
end
```

Comment: You've given me an enormous amount to go off here and taught me a lot. Thank you.